Roblox Animation Loading, Not Loading
I was following a tutorial on making a Roblox Combat System, but I ran into a problem with animation loading. For some reason, it can't load the animation and tells me that the LoadAnimation() function needs to load an animation object, which I've tried keyframes and even just added an Animation Object with an animation ID of "17401496431" and nothing changes. (This is a server script)
local MH = require(game.ServerStorage.modules.MuchachoHitbox)
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Combat Event")
local MaxCombo = 5

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        character:SetAttribute("Combo", 1)
    end)
end)

local function SetCombo(character)
    local combo = character:GetAttribute("Combo")

    if combo < MaxCombo then
        character:SetAttribute("Combo", combo + 1)
    else
        character:SetAttribute("Combo", 1)
    end
end

remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    local character = player.Character
    local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local rootPart = humanoid.RootPart
    local animator = humanoid:WaitForChild("Animator")

    local combo = character:GetAttribute("Combo")
    local attacking = character:GetAttribute("Attacking")

    if attacking then return end
    character:SetAttribute("Attacking", true)

    local animations = game.ReplicatedStorage["hit anims"]:GetChildren()
    local animation = animator:LoadAnimation(animations[combo])

    local hitbox = MH.CreateHitbox()
    hitbox.Size = Vector3.new(6, 6, 6)
    hitbox.Offset = CFrame.new(0, 0, -2.5)
    hitbox.CFrame = rootPart
    -- hitbox.Visualizer = false

    animation.Stopped:Connect(function()
        character:SetAttribute("Attacking", nil)
        hitbox:Stop()
    end)

    hitbox.Touched:Connect(function(hit, hum)
        if hum == humanoid then return end

        hum:TakeDamage(5)
    end)

    animation:Play()
    task.wait(0.16)
    hitbox:Start()

    SetCombo(character)
end)

I'm expecting the animation to load properly and play without any errors. I followed the tutorial exactly and it didn't have any errors then.

What is ClassName of the children in animations?

Animations can ONLY be played if you own them. Meaning, if the animation is owned by someone else or on a group (Even it its yours), it will not play.

I made and published the animation so I don’t know why it’s not working. They are named from 1 to 5

@Kaj You will need to give permission to use your animations if you are developing a group experience, even if you are the group owner and made the animations.

I haven’t published this as a group experience. This is made and listed as made by me only. I’m very confused by this since I did something similar on another game I worked on and it worked just fine. (Also made by me alone)

@Ryan_Luu the class names are numbered 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
